# Mac Mini M1 Install Postgresql 12

Tags: macos-big-sur, postgresql-12, apple-m1

Used `homebrew` to install `postgresql@12` and it won't allow me to move forward after "starting".

```
~ ❯ brew services start postgresql@12                                                                                                             21s 06:05:13
==> Successfully started `postgresql@12` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12)

~ ❯ brew services list                     
Name          Status  User Plist
nginx         error   root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
pgbouncer     stopped
postgresql@12 error   rich /Users/rich/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12.plist
unbound       stopped

~ ❯ psql -U postgres
zsh: command not found: psql

~ ❯ sudo su - postgres
su: unknown login: postgres

~ ❯ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Load failed: 5: Input/output error

~ ❯ nmap localhost
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-10 06:14 EST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000054s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
80/tcp    open  http
443/tcp   open  https
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
5900/tcp  open  vnc
49159/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds
```

How can I get this working?  It's a first install on a brand new box.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the solution (currently) is to use the `postgres.app` available at [postgressapp.com](https://postgresapp.com)